# what are index partitioning and mirror query components in SharePoint2010 Search?

Tags: search

what are index partitioning and mirror query components in SharePoint2010 Search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Enterprise Search Blog has a post describing [Index partitions, query components & mirrors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/enterprisesearch/sharepoint-2010-search-dogfood-part-3-query-performance-optimization).